# how to configure ipaddress filters with system-config-firewall

Tags: iptables, firewall, fedora, rules

The system is Fedora 23. The objective is to allow a specific port or range of ports access from a limited set of ip addresses. This can be done manually withe the following rule:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp -s 10.0.0.0/16 --dport 5900:5904 -j ACCEPT
```

However without it being represented in /etc/sysconfig/system-config-firewall it is lost across upgrades or changes in other rules via system-config.firewall. Is there a way using system-config-firewall to configure rules similar to the one above?

Comment: Save yourself a bunch of trouble and use firewalld instead.

Answer (score 0):

iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables